# I want selenium to click on a link

Tags: python, selenium, web2py

I have a link which is automaticaly generated :

```
<a href="LINK">Download</a>
```

I want selenium to click on Download whatever the `LINK` is.

Comment: What did you try? Did you had a look here : http://seleniumhq.org/docs/02_selenium_ide.html#locating-hyperlinks-by-link-text ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text('Download').click()
```